# How to disable caching of AJAX requests in Angular in IE

Tags: angularjs, http, internet-explorer

I have an angular application that makes HTTP GET calls to the server. It works fine on Chrome & Firefox. However, I figured out that IE caches the GET response, and after I do a POST, I need to call the same GET request and get the new updated response but IE caches it. I want to disable caching just for IE.
I tried using a

```
'If-None-Match': '*'
```

request header on my GET calls, but then that disables caching for everything. Is there a way to do that conditionally for IE only? Or is there another way to disable it?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
```

OR

JS

```
if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
}
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Pragma = "no-cache";
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["If-Modified-Since"] = "0";
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the above info I was able to get this working on a one-off request inside a controller instead of changing the global defaults:

```
var configOptions = {
    headers: {
        common: {
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "If-Modified-Since": "0",
            "Pragma": "no-cache"
        }
    }
};

$http.get("path/to/file.json", configOptions)
    .then(function (response){
        //do stuff
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

$http, in IE. Not having response code of 200 or 304. It just uses local cache.

Try adding headers to $httpProvider.

```
angular.module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName)
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    
    }    

    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}]);
```

Comment: I had a problem using this solution. I am also using Toastr in my Angular app and it seems that it requires the template to be cached.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old thread.
Only saying that I just tested it and none of disscussed headers are observed by IE11.

As IE takes only care of the url to determine if It is cached or not, I simply added a date in query string, like :

```
$http.get("https://myURLWithoutParameters"?t=" + new Date().getTime())
.then(function (response) {
  // Handle response
}, function (response) {
  // Error handling
});
```